# Elegant way to copy items of lists to another one

Tags: python

I want to copy the first two lists from a given nested `list`. I did the following:

```
list = [[10,20],[30,40,50],[0,0],[1,2,3]]
sList = []
x = 0
for i in list:
    if x == 2:
        break
    sList.append(i)
    x+=1
print ("%s" % sList)
```

My question is: is there another elegant way?

Comment: I want to get the first two lists `[10,20],[30,40,50]`. In other word, extracting the first two lists. My above method seems not elegant and I don't know how to make it better

Comment: @FriddyJoe, do you want actual copies of the sublists or just the references to the sublists?

Answer (score 2):

Just use slicing to get the first two items from a list. Also, don't use list as it shadows the built-in `list`:

```
list_ = [[10,20],[30,40,50],[0,0],[1,2,3]]

print(list_[:2])
```

Output:

```
[[10, 20], [30, 40, 50]]
```

An easy way to think of slicing is as follows:

```
list_[start:end:step]
```

Furthermore, as it was made clear to me, you are looking to actually extract this data in to a separate list. Therefore, you probably want to make use of the copy module, and use [deecopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Per the docs:

> For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is
>   sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the
>   other.

Therefore, your code can look like:

```
from copy import deepcopy

sub_list = deepcopy(list_[:2])
```

Comment: You probably want `copy.deepcopy(l[:2])` if the OP actually wants a copy or `list(map(list, (l[:2])))`

Comment: You're right. I see now they are actually creating a new list. I thought they were printing it simply for some reason. I've updated @PadraicCunningham. Thanks again. You've suggested a few other good edits to other answers of mine. Really appreciate the revisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing:

```
sList = list[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> list = [[10,20],[30,40,50],[0,0],[1,2,3]]
>> sList = list[:2]
>> print (sList)
[[10, 20], [30, 40, 50]]
```

Comment: This is REALLY elegant. I had a hunch that Python would include something elegant but since I am a beginner I couldn't get it. Thank you :)

Comment: What is the point of `print ("%s" % sList)`. Why not just print `sList`?

Comment: To make the code more similar to the original one.. The same reason I named the var `sList` instead of `sub_list`

Comment: Probably better not having it, or explaining why it is not needed. By just using it, you are implying that it is something that is necessary to print a list. It's a bit misleading based on how different your solution is from the code in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your example, just

```
sList = [oList[0], oList[1]]
```

or equivalently

```
sList = oList[:2]
```

In your sample code sList refers to the same lists as the original (which definitely shouldn't be called `list`) - if you actually want copies, use

```
sList = [list(e) for e in oList[:2]]
```

to duplicate the nested lists

Answer (score 0):

You can just take a list slice

```
Slist = list[0:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [[10, 20], [30, 40, 50], [0, 0], [1, 2, 3]]

sliced_list = [sub_list[:] for sub_list in my_list[:2]]

>>> sliced_list
 [[10, 20], [30, 40, 50]]
```

Note that `[:]` copies the list, so any change in either the first two elements of my_list or sliced_list will not be reflected in the other (unlike simple slicing).

`my_list[:2]` selects the first two sub lists from your list.

Slicing refers to the actual sublist, not a copy, as this example demonstrates.

*Copy with `[:]`*

```
sliced_list[0].append(30)

>>> sliced_list
[[10, 20, 30], [30, 40, 50]]

>>> my_list
[[10, 20], [30, 40, 50], [0, 0], [1, 2, 3]]
```

*Using slicing*

```
sliced_list = [sub_list for sub_list in my_list[:2]]
sliced_list[0].append(30)

>>> my_list
[[10, 20, 30], [30, 40, 50], [0, 0], [1, 2, 3]]
```